# (SSLError [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: windows, numpy, pip, installation

Can easily install numpy on my Mac and when trying to install numpy on my work Window computer it gived me the following error:

```
C:\Python27>python -m pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: 
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:726)'),)': 
/simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: 
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:726)'),)': 
/simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: 
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:726)'),)': 
/simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: 
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:726)'),)': 
/simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: 
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:726)'),)': 
/simple/numpy/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/numpy/: There was a problem 
confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', 
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/numpy/ (Caused by 
SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify 
failed (_ssl.c:726)'),)) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from 
versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpy
```

I am wondering if there is a block in the servers, like a firewall, at my work that cause this error. If so, what would you recommend to get around the error?

Comment: You need to upgrade Python to at least 2.7.9, better 2.7.15. And upgrade `pip` to 9.0.3 or 10.

Comment: I used the following code in my C:/Python27/ directory which I found from: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi?rq=1)    `python -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org numpy`